# Hide Text on scrolling down bottom of the page, Sencha 3 ExtJS

Tags: extjs

I am adding a text "Please scroll down" to the Terms and Conditions web page and the text should hide after reaching the bottom of the page. I created a container that shows the text on the entire page under View (Sencha Architect) but not sure how to hide it after scrolling to the bottom. I am trying to create a controller action under Controllers but it's not working. Attached is the code for TermsConditions controller. ItemID of the container containing text is scrollContainer

```
onAgreeClick: function(button, e, eOpts) {
        var store = Ext.data.StoreManager.lookup('UserObjectStore');
        var match = store.first(),
            showAnnouncements = match.get('announcementPageToVisit');
        if (showAnnouncements) {
            button = this.getBtnAnnouncements();
        } else {
            button = this.getBtnCustomerSearch();
        }
        this.simulateHeaderButtonClick(button);

        Ext.Ajax.request({
            url: '../abc/services/users/saveUser',
            method: 'GET',
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
            success: function (response, action) {

            },
            failure: function (response, action) {

            }
        });
    },
onDisagreeClick: function(button, e, eOpts) {
        Ext.Msg.confirm('','You must agree to the Terms and Conditions in order to continue. Press YES to go back or NO to exit.',
            function(answer) {
                if (answer === "no") {
                    var h = abc.app.getController('HeaderButton');
                    h.terminateApp('ok', null, null);
                }
            }
        );
    },
 BackToTaC: function(button, e, eOpts) {
        this.getTermsBtnContainer().hide();
        this.getTermsBackContainer().show();
        this.getScrollContainer().hide();
        this.getBtnAnnouncements().toggle();
        this.getBody().getLayout().setActiveItem(6);
    },
var me = this;
dataview.getEl().on('scroll', function(e, t) {
    if(t.scrollHeight - t.scrollTop - t.clientHeight === 0) {
    }

});// I already tried to hide under this but it doesn't work
  onTermsBeforeShow: function(component, eOpts) {
        var me = this;
        var termsView = component.down('dataview');
        var termsStore = termsView.getStore();
        termsStore.getProxy().actionMethods = {create: 'POST', read: 'POST', update: 'POST', destroy: 'POST'};
        termsStore.load();
           },
```

Answer (score 0):

I have had similar requirements for Extjs Panel and I handled them by getting  the height of the grid and comparing the height with the current Y Position of the grid.

In the panel page , I had

```
var toBeAbsoluted = this.getHeight() / 95 * 100; // approximation 95% seemed optimum in my case
if(this.getY() >= (this.getHeight() - toBeAbsoluted ))
buttonToHide.hide()
```